# escape on Doxygen and what exactly # means?

Tags: c++, escaping, doxygen

I was trying to escape `#` in Doxygen to present `#####EXAMPLE#####` in the description of one method in my documentation, I saw many suggestions but none works. Then I just used `\#` and it worked. Besides that I'm using `##` before and after my text and that's creating a new line, a space, around the text `####EXAMPLE####`. Now I wanna know if is it correct and what exactly `##` means in Doxygen.

```
/*!
 *\brief
 *##
 * \#\#\#\#\#EXAMPLE\#\#\#\#\#
 *##
 * This method bla bla bla
 *
*/
void Classe_name::method()
```

Answer (score 1):

It has three uses:

- When `MARKDOWN_SUPPORT` is enabled it can be used for headings, see [this section](http://www.doxygen.org/manual/markdown.html#md_headers) of the manual for details.
- When create unordered list you can use `-#` for each item, see [this section](http://doxygen.org/manual/lists.html) for more details.
- When linking to symbols, doxygen support the JavaDoc style of linking using Class#Method, or just #Global, instead of the native style Class::Method, or ::Global, see [this section](http://www.doxygen.org/manual/autolink.html) for more details.